# How to Copy a file from one directory to another using variables and arrays for both directories and files in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to copy a source file to a destination directory after some comparisons are made. The executable function only works if the names of directory and the files are spelled out. But I would like to use variables for directories and arrays for filenames.

Thanks.

```
 <?php

  $di1 = 'C:\TEMP\TEST';
  $di2 = 'C:\TEMPO\TEST';
  exec('Copy $di1\($isidor[$ee]) , $di2\($heli[$ww])'); 



  ?>
```

Comment: Why use `exec()` when PHP has a [copy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function for copying files?

Comment: You dont seem to want to do your own homework, so why should we. At least have some sort of attempt at it yourself, then ask for a bit of help! Maybe have a quick read of this [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And why are you wrapping `$isidor[$ee]` and `$heli[$ww]` in brackets?

Comment: Also read the relevant [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) about variables in strings

Comment: @Mark Baker: they are arrays.

Comment: If `$isidor[$ee]` is an array, then you can't simply "inject" it into a string; but wrapping it in brackets will actually have brackets in the string you're trying to create, which would be invalid as a Windows command

Comment: Yes, I thought that was a hindrance of php but it's due to Windows - I am still trying to figure out how to refer/read an array with the Copy function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shold try the built in copy function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

```
copy(
    $di1 . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $isidor[$ee],  
    $di2 . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $heli[$ww]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I did use both the copy function and the separator.